# Typescript unable to load module to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, module, web-deployment

I have just got started learning typescript and I am learning to import a module and this is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es6" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */,
    "module": "ES2015" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ] /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */,
    // "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    "sourceMap": true /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */,
    // "outFile": "./bundle.js" /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */,
    "outDir": "./dist" /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */,
    "rootDir": "./src" /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */,
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    "removeComments": true /* Do not emit comments to output. */,
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */
    "noEmitOnError": true,

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    // "noImplicitAny": false,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    "noUnusedLocals": true /* Report errors on unused locals. */,
    "noUnusedParameters": false /* Report errors on unused parameters. */,
    "noImplicitReturns": true /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */,
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node" /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */,
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */,
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    "experimentalDecorators": true /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules" // would be the default
  ]
}
```

As you can see, all of `ts` code will be generated in folder `dist` and the `app.ts` will be generated to `app.js` and imported in `index.html`

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>ProjectManager</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <script type="module" src="./dist/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <template id="project-input">
      <form>
        <div class="form-control">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input type="text" id="title" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
          <label for="description">Description</label>
          <textarea id="description" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
          <label for="people">People</label>
          <input type="number" id="people" step="1" min="0" max="10" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">ADD PROJECT</button>
      </form>
    </template>
    <template id="single-project">
      <li draggable="true">
        <h2></h2>
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
      </li>
    </template>
    <template id="project-list">
      <section class="projects">
        <header>
          <h2></h2>
        </header>
        <ul></ul>
      </section>
    </template>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I set the sript tag with property of `module` and src to `dist/app.js`. This is the whole structure of project
[image]

To see the detail of the project you can take a look at [this repo](https://gitlab.com/Khangithub/typepscript-udemy-course/-/tree/dev/9.Modules%20and%20Namespaces)
It compiled successfully but I got this error [image]

Please help me to deal with it, thank you so much and have a good day

Comment: Try `<script type="module" src="./dist/app.js"></script>`

Comment: sorry @kol, I updated that but it not work